# Circle on chart not following the ticks in axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am preparing chart in D3, and I defined the x-axis as the following:

```
const xaxis = d3.axisBottom()
    .ticks(d3.timeMonth.every(3))
    .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%b %y'))
    .scale(xScale);
```

The ticks did place once every 3rd month, however the circles in the chart still show a point on every month.

[image]

Here is how I created these circles:

```
lines.selectAll("line-circle")
        // .data(data=>data.values)
        .data(Q3bFileteredData)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", "data-circle")
        .attr("r", 5)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + 0 + ")")
        .attr("cx", function(d) {return xScale(d.date); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {return yScale(d.count); })
        .style("fill",  function(d) { return color(d.game) ; } )
        .append("text")
        .attr("dx", 10)
        .text(function(d){return d.rank})
    ;
```

How do I show circle at each 3rd month as in the axis?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up filtering the data for the months I wanted to show. I am not sure if that is the best solution, and I would surely like to hear what better solution are there.